# WCF Exchange Server Mail Transport from ASP

Tags: asp.net, wcf, exchange-server, wcf-binding

I have a requirement to send email through exchange server from an ASP page.

I am trying to implement the client/server scenario from this walk through, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397828.aspx , but the client code is directed at Mobile device.

Can anyone tell me what kind of Binding I need to use instead of WindowsMobileMailBinding? Thanks for any help you can offer.

Comment: If you just need to send mail, why not use `System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient`?

Comment: Hi, the requirement is to send mail through exchange, I will need to store sent mail etc....

Comment: Well, you would be using your Exchange server as the SMTP server.  But, take a look at the thread [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/exchange/en-US/f59da11b-b34e-41e0-adcd-4fc8509a1120/sending-mail-through-exchange-server-using-smtpclient-not-saving-email-in-the-sent-items-folder?forum=exchangesvrdevelopment) for perhaps something that would suit.

Comment: Excellent. I'll have a look, cheers for the advice.